# Black screen on boot after AMDGPU-Pro install (16.04)

Tags: drivers, 16.04, graphics, freeze, amd-graphics

I have been having some screen freezing issues on my new Ubuntu 16.04 system, and have been in the troubleshooting process for this issue. I thought it was a graphics driver problem, as I am running an AMD R9 380x card which was supposed to be fully supported by the open-source AMDGPU driver preinstalled with 16.04, but after looking around online, many people seem to have issues with. I thought the answer would be to install the recently released AMDGPU-Pro driver  [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx), following the instructions from [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx). However, when I reboot I am getting a black screen. Is there an easy way to revert my changes back? My machine was semi-functional with the freezing issue but now with no video at all is useless to me. How to proceed?

Answer (score 8):

When your system is booted and you're at the black screen issue the following keyboard command: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>. Login with your account. Then, run the command:

```
amdgpu-pro-uninstall
```

This should uninstall the driver and hopefully get you back working again.

Comment: This may happen if you have installed both nvidia and AMD drivers. You must also remove NVIDIA drivers and restore native ones. This helped me after following the above https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-uninstall-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

Answer (score 3):

1. Power off your system.
2. Power on the system, at the same time press on <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.
3. Select advanced recovery option & enter your password
4. Then type the command:

   ```
   mount -o remount, rw /
   ```

   This will give read write permission.
5. Run command:

   ```
   amdgpu-pro-uninstall
   ```

   This will uninstall amdgpu-pro from your system.
6. To shutdown system, run command: `poweroff` & then power on the system.

Answer (score 2):

For me fixed by entering command line with CTRL+F1 then removing the drivers

```
amdgpu-pro-uninstall
```

and reinstall using the --px option

```
./amdgpu-pro-install --px
```

Comment: Do you have a reference for the --px option? I can't find documentation on what it does.

Comment: @kalenpw, The readthedocs page mentions the `--px` flag [in this link](https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install-installing.html#id7).

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Press keyboard command: CTRL-ALT-F2 and Login with your account. Then, run the command:

```
amdgpu-pro-uninstall
sudo apt purge amdgpu*
```

Even after uninstalling amdgpu pro driver I still got black screen (even i executed the command X -configure), so I go to root shell by the option in recovery mode and removed the remaining driver. I guess it was amdgpu-dkms. I infer that Nvidia user should delete nvidia driver to get rid of black screen.

Comment: Same for me. Problem continued to occur with amdgpu-pro uninstalled, until I manually uninstalled amdgpu-dkms. Running Linux mint 19.3, kernel version 5.4.0-73. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to never use official AMD drivers with Debian-based distros like Ubuntu.

To remove them, from a terminal, run:

```
sudo apt remove firmware-amd-graphics
sudo apt remove firmware-linux-nonfree
```