# AMD Graphics drivers not working LTS 16.04, Radeon Rx480

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

Recently built a computer with specs:
Motherboard: ASUS Strix z270g
Intel 7600k
AMD Radeon Rx480
16G RAM

I am on Ubuntu LTS 16.04. According to AMD, their current AMDGPU-PRO drivers should support 16.04, but every time I try to install the drivers (found here: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx) I reboot and get stuck in an infinite login loop. Has anyone encountered this error and found a fix?

```
lspci -v | grep AMD

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480] (rev c7) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Radeon RX 480
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device aaf0
Subsystem: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device aaf0
```

Comment: So you have the same problem as this person? http://askubuntu.com/questions/880523/cant-login-after-installing-amdgpu-pro-16-60

Comment: Try to uninstall the driver following  [these steps](http://askubuntu.com/questions/799515/black-screen-on-boot-after-amdgpu-pro-install-16-04).