# Cannot boot end up always with a blinking cursor

Tags: 20.04, login-screen

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and it was working fine but after a recent reboot before which I had run some updates I can no longer log in as it never gets to the GUI login screen.

If I do <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>F2</kbd>,  I can login there but if I run something like `startx` that errors out and `xrandr` can't find any displays.

So I'm guessing this is a kernel issue? Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

Apologies for typos I'm writing from a phone

Comment: Same here. Able to boot only in recovery mode or using Alt+F* and `startx` but I don't have proper display drivers (there is warning that system works without hardware acceleration) and wifi. Spent few hours yesterday without success. Changed `splash silent` to `nosplash debug` in GRUB config so I can see that system stuck on "Reached target Host and Network Name Lookups". I also had to disable SSSD and re-install `sddm-theme-breeze` because it was somehow removed and login screen was broken. I've upgraded to 20.10 and forced 5.8.0 kernel but it didn't help.

Comment: Today small update popped up and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1903397 was mentioned in the description of kernel-related package, but it didn't help too. I've enabled proposed updates and updated everything, still without success. I have to work on recovery mode since booting using `startx` is barely usable (very slow animations, like Power Point slides).

Comment: I uninstalled amdgpu by running `amdgpu-pro-uninstall` and this got me back seems has worked for others here as well https://askubuntu.com/questions/799515/black-screen-on-boot-after-amdgpu-pro-install-16-04. But I still don't have the graphics card properly loaded as I can't extend to a 2nd monitor for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with several kernels and mainland didn't work for me.

Mainland problem:

- Kernels weren't signed

Installing kernels manually:

- tried installing 5.4.0.52 and 5.4.0.53 by doing the equivalent below:

`sudo apt install linux-image-5.4.0-53-generic linux-headers-5.4.0-53-generic`

That didn't work either - the mouse and wifi also didn't work.

What ultimately worked for me was:

`sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge`

Comment: I have secure boot disabled in BIOS so I could use unsigned kernel. But yeah, if you need secure boot, my answer does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Success!

I was able to boot normally, with fully working system. What I did was installing mainline tool (method #3 from here → https://linuxhint.com/update_ubuntu_kernel_20_04/):

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mainline
```

(I had to edit sources list and change from `groovy` to `focal`)

Then I installed `5.9.12` kernel using Mainline installer and after rebooting everything worked fine (I saw that even earlier because my external monitor started to work while booting).

Additionally I've removed `wireguard` package because there was warnings while building GRUB images and since I don't use WG anymore I just uninstalled it. But I believe actual fix was delivered in 5.9 kernel.

Comment: interesting do you know what linux kernel you were on before? I'm at 5.4.0.56 when I run `uname -r`

Comment: I had `5.4.0-56`, `5.8.0-29` (both signed) and `5.8.0-31` (unsigned), each of them had the same issue.

Comment: And were you on an amd processor, did you have to install amdgpu?

Comment: I didn't touch `amdgpu` in any way, before the crash and after that. I just tested many kernels and 5.9.12 actually worked :-)

Comment: FYI:

-> % dpkg --list | egrep -i 'amdgpu'                             
ii  libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64                                        2.4.102-1ubuntu1                                            amd64        Userspace interface to amdgpu-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime
ii  xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu                                   19.1.0-2                                                    amd64        X.Org X server -- AMDGPU display driver

Comment: do you know if what you have done will allow ubuntu to update to kernels in the futrue? or have you overridden that part by manually selecting a kernel?

Comment: @evan54 Honestly I don't know how it will act in the future, for now I don't think about it since I needed working system for my work :-) I think (and hope) that if kernel delivered in 21.04 will be newer than installed with `mainline` it will be updgraded. Otherwise, I'll install it manually.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd add because I tried all these possible answers and it didn't work.

I have an old Nvidia GPU (GeForce 9600 GT) and I had to reinstall the display manager, reinstall the desktop environment and then reinstall the graphics driver. It seems that an update made the normal driver fail (`nvidia-340`) and I needed a different driver.

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```